# Why does my activerecord query return nothing if relational records do not exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, rspec

Here is my search method for customers:

```
    def customer_search(key, session) # Tested
      digits = key.gsub(/\D+/, '')
      digits = key if (digits == '')
      Customer.joins(:emails, :phone_numbers)
        .where(environment_id: session[:environment_id])
        .where("first_name ~* :key OR last_name ~* :key OR emails.address ~* :key OR phone_numbers.number ~* :digits", key: key, digits: digits)
    end
```

Email and PhoneNumber are both classes, and Customer has_many :emails and has_many :phone_numbers.

When I use this method in production it works great, but all my customers have phone numbers and emails.  There are probably some records that do not have an email or do not have a phone_number.

When I was running my rspec test, the test sets up the customer in a before block and then queries on the name:

```
    before(:each) do
      @c  = FactoryGirl.create :customer
    end

    it 'should perform a customer search' do
      session = {environment_id: 1}
      key     = 'test'
      result  = Customer.customer_search(key, session).all
      expect(result.length).to eq(1)
      expect(result[0].first_name).to eq('Test')
    end
```

FactoryGirl defines the first_name as 'Test' so this query is just checking that I find this customer within this environment (session) and we ignore case.

I get result = nil when I DO NOT create phone_number and email records for this customer.  If I change the before to :

```
    before(:each) do
      @c  = FactoryGirl.create :customer
      Email.create(customer_id: @c.id, address: "customer@gmail.com")
      PhoneNumber.create(customer_id: @c.id, number: "8086565647")
    end

    it 'should perform a customer search' do
      session = {merchant_id: 1}
      key     = 'test'
      result  = Customer.customer_search(key, session).all
      expect(result.length).to eq(1)
      expect(result[0].first_name).to eq('Test')
    end
```

Then it returns the proper result.

My question is why?  Why does this SQL return nothing IF no records exist?:

"SELECT "customers".* FROM "customers" INNER JOIN "emails" ON "emails"."customer_id" = "customers"."id" INNER JOIN "phone_numbers" ON "phone_numbers"."customer_id" = "customers"."id" WHERE "customers"."environment_id" = 1 AND (first_name ~* 'test' OR last_name ~* 'test' OR emails.address ~* 'test' OR phone_numbers.number ~* '')"

Can we not INNER JOIN but if there isn't a record just gracefully continue on like nothing is wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You are creating a inner join, and this is how inner joins behave. You get nothing when the there is no record in the connected table. You need to create an outer join if you do not want this.

To create an outer join, you need to give a string fragment to the `joins` method
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#using-a-string-sql-fragment